# error: expected primary-expression before ',' token

Tags: c++, arduino-ide

I'm gettng an error "error: expected primary-expression before ',' token" in the following line of code - I have initialized an array with 220 ints. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const PROGMEM int P7Val[] = {1635,1635,1635,1635,1635,1630,1630,1630,1630,1630,1625,1625,1625,1625,1620,1620,1620,1620,1615,1615,1615,1610,1610,1610,1605,1605,1605,1600,1600,1600,1595,1595,1595,1590,1590,1590,1585,1585,1580,1580,1580,1575,1575,1570,1570,1570,1565,1565,1560,1560,1555,1555,1555,1550,1550,1545,1545,1540,1540,1535,1535,1535,1530,1530,1525,1525,1520,1520,1515,1515,1510,1510,1505,1505,1500,1500,1495,1495,1490,1490,1490,1485,1485,1480,1480,1475,1475,1470,1470,1465,1465,1460,1460,1455,1455,1450,1450,1445,1445,1440,1440,1435,1435,1430,1430,1425,1425,1420,1420,1415,1415,1410,1410,1405,1405,1400,1400,1395,1395,1390,1390,1385,1385,1380,1380,1380,1375,1375,1370,1370,1365,1365,1360,1360,1355,1355,1350,1350,1345,1345,1345,1340,1340,1335,1335,1330,1330,1325,1325,1320,1320,1320,1315,1315,1310,1310,1305,1305,1305,1300,1300,1295,1295,1290,1290,1290,1285,1285,1280,1280,1275,1275,1275,1270,1270,1265,1265,1265,1260,12601635,1635,1635,1635,1635,1630,1630,1630,1630,1630,1625,1625,1625,1625,1620,1620,1620,1620,1615,1615,1615,1610,1610,1610,1605,1605,1605,1600,1600,1600,1595,1595,1595,1590,1590,1590,1585,1585,1580,1580,1580,1575,1575,1570,1570,1570,1565,1565,1560,1560,1555,1555,1555,1550,1550,1545,1545,1540,1540,1535,1535,1535,1530,1530,1525,1525,1520,1520,1515,1515,1510,1510,1505,1505,1500,1500,1495,1495,1490,1490,1490,1485,1485,1480,1480,1475,1475,1470,1470,1465,1465,1460,1460,1455,1455,1450,1450,1445,1445,1440,1440,1435,1435,1430,1430,1425,1425,1420,1420,1415,1415,1410,1410,1405,1405,1400,1400,1395,1395,1390,1390,1385,1385,1380,1380,1380,1375,1375,1370,1370,1365,1365,1360,1360,1355,1355,1350,1350,1345,1345,1345,1340,1340,1335,1335,1330,1330,1325,1325,1320,1320,1320,1315,1315,1310,1310,1305,1305,1305,1300,1300,1295,1295,1290,1290,1290,1285,1285,1280,1280,1275,1275,1275,1270,1270,1265,1265,1265,1260,1260,1255,1255,1255,1250,1250,1245,1245,1245,1240,1240,1235,1235,1235,1230,1230,1225,1225,1225,1220,1220,1215,1215,1215,1210,1210,1210,1205,1205,1200,1200,1200,1195,1195,1195,1190,1190,1185,1185,1185,1180,1180,,1255,1255,1255,1250,1250,1245,1245,1245,1240,1240,1235,1235,1235,1230,1230,1225,1225,1225,1220,1220,1215,1215,1215,1210,1210,1210,1205,1205,1200,1200,1200,1195,1195,1195,1190,1190,1185,1185,1185,1180,1180};
```

Comment: #include<iostream> using namespace std; class sample { int x; public: int get_val(int a); void show_val(); }; int sample::get_val(int a) { x=a; } void sample::show_val() { cout<<" "<<x; } int main() { sample obj[3]; for(int i=10;i<13;i++) { obj[i].get_val(int a); } for(int i=10;i<13;i++) { obj[i].show_val(); } return 0; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You have a comma missing: `1260,12601635,1635,`
2. You have an extra comma: `1180,1180,,1255,1255`

If you reformat your list into a nice regular table (say 10 entries per line) across multiple lines these things instantly become apparent.